# Bash script cause undeletable file

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I'm learning bash and have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

mv myfile.txt myfileBACKUP.txt


echo "yo i love taylorswift
and i like blink182
ok done">> myfile.txt

mv myfileBACKUP.txt myfile.txt
```

the problem is that after I run script I still have myfileBACKUP.txt left and when I try to delete it I get error similar to this guy's `The file cannot be moved to the trash.`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/164026/unable-to-delete-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Basically im looking to write a script which backs up an original file, create a new file and do something with the new file, then restore the original file.

Any help on how to do that and / or why I'm getting this garbage file leftover?

edit:

file permission from ls -la (the bad files doesn't show up in ls)

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 odroid odroid 147 Dec 23 02:08 autodownloadv2.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 odroid odroid  45 Dec 23 02:59 myfile.txt
```

also the first time I run this myfile.txt doesn't exist so it throws an error I dont know if that has anything to do with this.

Comment: What are the permissions of the file and the directory?

Comment: @glennjackman see edit

Comment: I tried your script and in both cases I'm able to move the files to the trash. What about the permissions of the directory? Are you doing this in your `/home` or in an external device?

Comment: @nxnev Do you ever get myfileBACKUP.txt leftover? That's the file I cant delete not the .sh and myfile.  drwxrwxr-x is directory permission.  Also can you spam run the script really fast like 10x?

Comment: @bakalolo Actually in both cases I end up having `myfile.txt` but not `myfileBACKUP.txt`. In the first case, it's not even created because `myfile.txt` doesn't exist in the first place so both `mv` statements fail. In the second case, the second `mv` statement supersedes `myfile.txt` with `myfileBACKUP.txt`. And what do you really mean with "_can you spam run the script really fast like 10x?_"? I think the script runs, by default, at the max speed possible.

Comment: Why do you think you still have `myfileBAKUP.txt` left when the script runs, if you don't see it in `ls`?

Comment: If you want to run the script 10 times fast: `for in in {1..10}; do ./scriptname; done`

Comment: Seems like you need to refresh your file browser after the script has finished, and before you try to move a file into the trash that probably doesn't exist any more...